# Nginx ssl_trusted_certificate directive problem

Tags: security, nginx, client-certificates, mutual-authentication

I have my nginx configured with client_certificate authentication:

```
ssl_client_certificate  /etc/nginx/ssl/cas.pem;
ssl_verify_client optional; 
ssl_verify_depth 2;
```

And is working fine, but I need to NOT send the CAs to the client during the handshake.

I've seen http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_trusted_certificate in the documentation. So, I've changed it to:

```
ssl_trusted_certificate  /etc/nginx/ssl/cas.pem;
ssl_verify_depth 2;
```

But now ssl_client_verify is always to NONE, like if there wasn't sent any certificate info in the request.

[EDIT] Saw in wireshark that actually the client is not sending the certificate.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You still need `ssl_verify_client {other than off};` to get any client auth/client cert at all.

Comment: Then it says this message:nginx: [emerg] no ssl_client_certificate for ssl_client_verify